# Trying to add icons in Material UI table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Hi I am using Material UI table in one of my projects. I have a design similar to this -

[image]

I have to use icons inside the tables

This is the code I have done so far -

```
export const TableBodyComponent: React.FC<ITableBody> = ({
    col
  }) => {
    const { classes } = useStyles();
    return (
      <TableRow>
        { col.map(c => (
          <TableCell className={classes.roleTable} key={c}> {c} </TableCell>
        ))}
      </TableRow>
    );
  };
```

And I am using TableBodyComponent like this -

```
<TableBodyComponent
  col={data}
/>
```

And data is something I am using it form INITIAL_DATA below -

```
"INITIAL_DATA": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "client_name": "XYZ",
                "industry": "Automobile",
                "origin": "India",
                "managers": "test"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "client_name": "ABC",
                "industry": "Automobile",
                "origin": "India",
                "managers": "test"
            },
```

I am getting the below result so far-

[image]

How can I use icons inside the MUI table.

Comment: Please share your code and show what you have reached so far.

Comment: We can't very well help address issues with code we can't see. Can you edit your post to include a relevant [mcve]?

Comment: I have tried adding minimum code above.

Comment: Is `TableCell` the component rendering the row of data? *This* it seems is the component likely to be rendering the icons.

Comment: Yes TableCell is rendering each row of data and I want to show icons in each row.

Comment: Ok, then please share this `TableCell` component so we can see how it's rendering these icons.

Comment: TableCell component is imported from Material UI - 
`import TableCell from '@mui/material/TableCell'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250363/discussion-between-nikhil-and-drew-reese).

Comment: I see. Please edit the post to include all relevant code as part of a [mcve] so we've enough context to reproduce any issues ourselves.

Comment: Thanks @DrewReese, I have achieved the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mui components are like a LEGO, you need to build your own table by yourself with the help of MUI components.

See an example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-cdn-un73ko?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Yup, thanks @OndrejHj04. I have achieved the result by tweaking the TableCell component.

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved now and below is what I have done -

```
export const TableBodyComponent: React.FC<ITableBody> = ({
    col,
    editActionHandler,
    deleteActionHandler
  }) => {
    const { classes } = useStyles();
    return (
      <TableRow>
        { col.map(c => (
          <TableCell className={classes.roleTable} key={c}> {c} </TableCell>
        ))}

       // Added the icons inside the new Table Cell
       <TableCell>
         <ModeEditOutlineOutlinedIcon onClick={editActionHandler} sx={{ paddingR ight: '20px' }}/>
         <DeleteOutlineOutlinedIcon onClick={deleteActionHandler}/>
       </TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    );
  };
```